# Checking if merge has happened in smart contract

Tags: proof-of-stake, eth-2.0, beacon-chain

Is it possible to check whether or not the merge has happened using a smart contract? Preferably completely on-chain, but some trustworthy decentralized oracle that tells me could work too.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that one way would be to look the [difficulty bomb](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-4345). It is not 100% reliable, but the merge will occur once the PoW on the execution layer reach the `TERMINAL_TOTAL_DIFFICULTY` (see [https://github.com/ethereum/consensus-specs/tree/dev/specs/bellatrix](https://specs/bellatrix)).

Edit: I found this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LdAlzFPaJpQ&t=1395s) which answers your question. I recommend listening to the whole, but the part that interests you is at 12:30. Tim Beiko explains that the diffulty value will become the randao going thus from a 64 bits value to a 256 one.

Here is a visual representation:
[image]
(source: https://blog.ethereum.org/2021/11/29/how-the-merge-impacts-app-layer/)